# How can I approach index of one dimensional array in c programming?

Tags: c, string

```
input
1 2
2 3
1 5
5 2
5 6
4 7
```

If i receive 6 strings including blank, I want to change them to integers such as

```
output
12
23
15
52
56
47
```

how can i make this program in c ??

```
int input_strings(int arraySize){
scanf("%d",&arraySize); 
char * names[arraySize];
char buffer[30]; 
int n = 0;
int l = 0;

while ( n < arraySize ) {
    scanf("%s", buffer);
   
    
    l = strlen(buffer);
    if (l > 0){
        char* newstrptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (l + 1));
        strcpy(newstrptr, buffer);
        names[n] =  newstrptr;
        n++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}



for(n=0;n<arraySize;n++){
    printf("%02d: %s\n", n, names[n]);
    free(names[n]);
}
return 0;
}
```

after this code , there will be names[0] ~ names[5] 
First question,  I want to delete blank that is 2nd index of names[0] .
For example , names[0] = "1 2" , and I want to delete and make "12" .

Second, How can i approach 2nd index of array?
If new_names[0] = "12" , then How can I approach 2nd index of new_names[0]?
should I use two dimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

Does it answer your question ? (I assume that your individual numbers cannot have more than 1 digit)

Question 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char * str = malloc(4);
    strcpy(str, "1 2");
    str[1] = str[2];
    str[2] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", str); //==> "12"
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Question 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char * str = "12";
    int n = str[1] - '0';
    printf("%d\n", n); //==> 2
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you!! But I want to deal with more than one individual number .. . . .

Comment: In that case you must explain how you plane to manage that : for instance, if you have a string "231", what are the two numbers, 23 and 1 or 2 and 31 ? And what is the underlying logic ? You can not expect a solution for a problem you don't completely explain.